# Using i18next to build a menu

Tags: javascript, json, i18next

I have a page using i18next on node.

In the translation files, there are translations (duh) for various things (it's like a database for little helper snippets)

now i want to build a page, where the user can view them individually.

## idea

i want to access the loaded `xx-translation.json` and make a (dropdown?) menu containing all the entries in one namespace

```
{
    "category": {
        "subcategory": {    // i want to get ["bla", "blu", "bli"] as result
            "bla"    : "ble",
            "blu"    : "blo",
            "bli"    : "bly"
        }
    }
}
```

i'm thinking about a simple loop like

```
var amountOfEntries = translationJSON.category.subcategory.length;
for (var i = 0; i < amountOfEntries; i++) {
    $('#menu').   //append that entry somehow
}
```

## tldr questions

is there a way to access the translation.json inside my "normal" js and count the number of entries?
and
how can i build a menu piece by piece with the entries? (this is bonus, i think i'd manage to do that. the main question is the first one)

thanks

Comment: I just posted an answer to your question, but I think I may have misunderstood what you were asking.  Are you saying that the translation.json file in your node application, but you want to access it from your client-side javascript?

Comment: the translation file is ajax-loaded on the clientside (`$.i18n.init({//etc, resGetPath: '/locales/__lng__-__ns__.json'), //etc)}`. there are GET requests to the JSON files that i can see in devtools and i can switch them live (without reload = they must be somewhere in the browser). now i am wondering how (if) i can access those files from the (also clientside) browser.js to count the entries

Comment: Updated my answer. I'm not super familiar with i18next, so let me know if that's not what you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [lodash.js](http://lodash.com) for some good collection utility functions.  You can iterate over the object with something like:

```
_.each(subcategory, function(val, key){
    $(".menu").append("<li>" + key + ": " + val + "</li>");
});
```

is that helpful?

**UPDATE**

After clarifying your question in the comments above, I think what you're looking for is either [getResource()](http://i18next.com/docs/api/#get-resource) or [getResourceBundle()](http://i18next.com/docs/api/#get-resource-bundle).

Comment: it seems to be the right direction. there were some problems (v1.10 instead of 2.x), but i found the same function in the old doc and i now managed to have a count of the entries. going to try to bend that into what i need :) thanks

Comment: i'm fighting with an issue... maybe you have an idea?
in the init-callback of i18next, `i18n.getResourceBundle('en')` works and retrieves just what i want.
but if i move that exact same function to another file, it does not.
`var lng = i18n.lng()` gives the correct language, but `i18n.getResourceBundle(lng);` returns an empty object (same if i call it with `'en'`). i can't figure out why.... :/

Comment: nevermind, it was actually just the obvious thing.. inside the callback, all the resources were already there, outside, they weren't yet. gonna have to fiddle around with that a little more :)